# diffeomorphism inbetween two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the function

$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \space\space f(x, y) := \pmatrix{x(1-y) \cr x y}$$

Now first, why is $f$ continuously differentiable?

Then, I want to prove that $f$ transforms the strip $(0, \infty) \times (0, 1)$ diffeomorph into the quadrant $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$.

What I thought: would it already be sufficient for the first statement to determine the Jacobi matrix? Or would I have to do more to show it's indeed continuously differentiable?

And in order to be a diffeomorphism, $f$ needs to be bijective on the said domain, and $f$ aswell as $f^{-1}$ need to be continuously differentiable. I don't really know how to show this though.

Comment: $f$ is continuously differentiable because each component is continuously differentiable, being products of continuously differentiable functions (i.e. polynomials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is given by polynomial functions in $x$ and $y$ and so is continuously differentiable.

Let $u=x(1-y)$ and $v=xy$ so that $f(x,y)=(u,v)$.

You can solve these equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$:
$x=u+v$ and $y=\dfrac{v}{u+v}$.

Thus, $f$ has an inverse given by rational functions and so is continuously differentiable. Note that $u+v\ne0$ for $u,v>0$.

(It is not always that easy or even possible to find a rational inverse for a polynomial function.)